# Java - How to pass a List type to a HashMap?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method `public static Object getMostOccurringObject(List<?> list)` which should return the most occurring object in the given list, or null if there are multiple objects with the highest occurrence.

In order to achieve this, I need to use a HashMap with the objects in list as key and the frequency of that object as value: `HashMap<[type of list], Integer>`.

This is what I've come up with:

```
public static <T> T getMostOccuringObject(List<T> list) {
    HashMap<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (T item : list) {
        if (map.containsKey(item)) {
            map.put(item, map.get(item) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(item, 1);
        }
    }
    int max = Collections.max(map.values());
    if (Collections.frequency(map.values(), max) == 1) {
        for (T object : map.keySet()) {
            if (map.get(object).equals(max)) {
                return object;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I'm not sure if this will do what I want. The code does compile. Could anyone confirm for me if this works, and if not, how I can make it work?

Comment: Do you mean if that will compile (which you can surely test yourself) or if you can solve this problem with such a HashMap (for which a simple "yes, it will work" won't help you, since you'll need to figure out how from there anyway)?

Comment: The code does compile, but I'm not sure if the HashMap has the same type as the List.

Comment: There isn't really a reason why there should be the wild card `?` instead of a type. Also the pitfall, is that the objects in the list must have properly implemented the hashcode/equals methods, other wise your frequency will be 1 for each item.

Comment: You don't want a `HashMap<[type of list], Integer>` for this problem.

Comment: @JoeC I've updated my code. How else would you do it? (without Java 8)

Comment: *Could anyone confirm for me if this works, and if not, how I can make it work?* No.  We are a question-and-answer site, not a unit test suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a wildcard `?` as the key to your `Map`, no elements will be able to be added; the `Map#put` method expects a capture type, and will not compile when you attempt to add any `Object` to it.  Instead, you can use a generic:

```
public static <T> T getMostOccuringObject(List<T> c) {
    Map<T, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<>();
    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Actually, the generic type is a must; otherwise elements from `List c` cannot be inserted as keys into `Map frequency` without unchecked type casting.

Comment: Could I also use Object as type rather than a generic type, since I already return an Object?

Comment: @Izruo I don't even think an explicit cast will fix it, as the `Map<?, Integer>` expects a capture type, so it just wouldn't compile.

Comment: @HYBR1D but why return the object, if you can return the same type as the list? If I call `getMostOccuringObject(stringList)`, I'd want to get a `String` as a result, not an `Object`

Comment: @HYBR1D Type erasure erases the generic to `Object` at runtime regardless.  If your `List` only contains objects of a single type (or children of that type), use a generic!

Answer (score 0):

the following works for you. and also make sure parameters should have proper hashcode&equals method

```
public static <T> Object getMostOccuringObject(List<T> c) {
HashMap<T, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<>();
// rest of the code
```

}

refer:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html